# Different behaviour of js in vscode and browser console

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, console

I have a code that results different in vscode terminal and browser console. why?

```
var length = 10;
function fn() {
    console.log(this.length);
}

var obj = {
   length: 5,
   method: function(fn) {
      fn();
      arguments[0]();
   }
};

obj.method(fn, 1);
```

it logs 10 and 2 in browser console

```
10
2
```

but it logs different in vscode terminal. script use to run code is 'node file.js'

```
undefined
2
```

Comment: Even in web browsers, ECMA/JavaScript is not always the same.

Answer (score 0):

In console of browser , you can visualize  tree structure of DOM , while you can't in vscode.
You can see different behaviour of code console.log(window.document) in console in vscode js file.
in console you can redeclare let variable but in vscode js file you cannot redeclare it,